# Adding a value to the middle of an array without replacing an existing value in java

Tags: java, arrays

I am researching the difference of arrays and Arraylists. Can anyone clarify if it is possible to add an element to the middle of an array without replacing the existing value (like what the x.add() would to for an arraylist)?
For example: if I had an array of fruit [apples, pears, peaches, nectarines] and I want to insert plums [apples, pears, plums, peaches, nectarines]. Would this be possible and how would it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `array` size is fixed, so normally it's  complicated to add an element into an array.
But in special cases it is possible:

It is only possible if the array is not yet fully filled.
Like  `[apples, pears, peaches, nectarines, NULL, NULL]`

inserting is then possible if the current size, which you have to record on a separate place, is smaller than the array size.

Inserting then works using `System.arraycopy()`, where you first move all elements at inserting position and above to one position to the right. Then you add the new element.

The result would be  `[apples, pears, plums, peaches, nectarines, NULL]`
leaving yet place for one more element.

Java's `ArrayList` uses this technic to provide a dynamic growing array.

In most cases it's better to use `ArrayList` for this task. In special cases where you have to read millions of elements such a self managed "growing" array is much more memory efficient (e.g 4 times less the memory, because `ArrayList` always uses Objects while array could also use primitive types, and they need less memory).

**Note:**
If one reads you question puristic the answer is "No", because you showed a fully filled array. The only chance to add any more element is to allocate a new array with bigger size and copy the old elements and the new one. But then you have a new array. The access to that array must be encapsulated that no one can reference it, except the class which manages the adding and getting values from it. Just look at the source code of ArrayList to get an Idea.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible.

You would need to allocate a new array larger than the existing one and copy everything over to it in the new positions.

Answer (score 0):

**No.** Arrays have fixed length, and cannot be resized.

Answer (score 0):

An array is a continuous region of memory - so no, you cannot add an element in the middle of an existing array.  `ArrayList` is a `List` backed by an array.  When necessary, `ArrayList` will allocate a new array and copy existing values into the newly allocate array.

```
392     public void add(int index, E element) {
393         rangeCheckForAdd(index);
394 
395         ensureCapacity(size+1);  // Increments modCount!!
396         System.arraycopy(elementData, index, elementData, index + 1,
397                          size - index);
398         elementData[index] = element;
399         size++;
400     }
```

Read the code for ArrayList [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.add%28java.lang.Object%29).

Answer (score 0):

```
const array = [1,2,3];

array.splice(2,0,5); \\ (index, number of items you want to replace, item to be replaced with separated by commas)

console.log(array); \\ [1,5,3]

array2 = [1,2,3];
array2.splice(1,0,4,5);
console.log(array2); \\ [1, 4, 5, 2, 3]
```

Hope this helps the JS Devs